# How to list out all the deployed versions in activiti explorer

Tags: scala, activiti

I have created a model in  activiti modeler and deployed it.As there are some changes,i have edited the model and redeployed it.Each time it has created the different process definition id.so far, i have the list of process definition id's to the same model as bellow:

```
 (testprocess:1:657516,testprocess:2:657520,testprocess:3:657524,testprocess:4:657528)
```

In  activiti explorer,under the 'Deployed Process definitions' tab I'm able to see only the latest deployed process(i.e., process which have process definition id as testprocess:4:657528)

Is there any way to see all the list of process under this tab(Deployed Process definitions)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get them on Explorer UI but they have provided an API for querying process definitions called `HistoricProcessInstance`. you can use that and query desired results. try -

```
List<HistoricProcessInstance> listOfOldDefinition = execution.getEngineServices().getHistoryService().createHistoricProcessInstanceQuery().processDefinitionKey("some-key").list();
        for(HistoricProcessInstance historicProcessInstance : listOfOldDefinition){
            System.out.println(historicProcessInstance.getName());
        }
```